# A big thank you to buddhism stackexchange

Tags: discussion

I have all the scholastic answers I need now, and stackexchange has really helped me formalize -- verbalize -- those questions.

So thanks: wish me luck in meditation.

Comment: ps i'm deleting my account just cos my answers aren't great.

Comment: May you be well :-)

Comment: Gad you got something out of it. Good luck in meditation.